# Is there a shortcut to find if system of linear equations has infinite or unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I got an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640554/set-of-linear-equation-has-no-solution-or-unique-solution-or-infinite-solution) from math stack exchange it uses matrices to determine whether the equation has unique or infinite solution. Is there any shortcut way to determine the same without having to take the matrices track? Can you post a reference to such shortcut solution?

Comment: Short answer: no. Slightly longer answer: I've never heard of any more efficient methods. Such methods would be of extreme interest to a lot of people, so I highly doubt they exist (or, they're complex enough that you'd only get a very slight gain for extremely large cases).

Comment: Also, don't be afraid of matrices. It's just standard elimination techniques (which are more efficient than substitution) written with a minimum of notation.